# Attempted a roll back from .Net 4.5 to 4.0 now getting missing assembly errors even though they are there

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I attempted a roll back of an Asp.Net MVC project from .Net 4.5 to .Net 4.0 to accommodate older servers in the hosting environment.

Now I am getting many similar errors:

```
Error   69  The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the
namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have removed the references in the project and re-added the references several times. Intellisense shows everything as being valid but when I go to compile I still get the above errors.

What is the proper way to rollback a project from 4.5 to 4?

Comment: This link might be slightly outdated, but it seemed to do the trick for few stack-users that were having the exact same problem as you [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, did you try cleaning the solution and/or deleting the contents of the "OBJ" folder?

Comment: Cleaned yes, deleting the obj folder no.